# Pandas Seaborn Install

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, seaborn

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running Python 2.7 I'm getting an install error from attempting to add the great looking Seaborn plotting package to my existing Pandas environment which is running fine.

Here's a snippet from the console containing the errors:

```
~$ pip install seaborn
running install_lib

creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/seaborn

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/seaborn': 
Permission denied
```

---

```
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tm/pip_build_moj0/seaborn/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-LvVao5-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_mojo/seaborn
Storing debug log for failure in /home/mojo/.pip/pip.log
```

Anyone have a resolution tip not available on the Seaborn github site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use sudo:

```
sudo pip install seaborn
```

*It requires sudo permission to write to `usr/local/lib`.*

Note: If you're using anaconda you won't need sudo to install via pip, once you've conda installed pip, though seaborn may also be available via conda.

Answer (score 7):

Personal installation is a good habit to get into:

`pip install --user seaborn`

However, there is an even easier way: as of writing [python XY maintains up-to-date builds of pandas *and* seaborn](https://launchpad.net/~pythonxy/+archive/ubuntu/pythonxy-devel) (among other useful packages), so all you have to do is

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pythonxy/pythonxy-devel
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-seaborn python-pandas
```

Note that this will only work with python 2.x; you will still need `pip3` to install the python 3.x packages.